# VS2010: Publish w/o mouse?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, publish

I'm in VS2010.  I have a project of type Web Application.  I want to publish it (equivalent of Right-Click,Publish on the project in Solution Explorer).  I don't want to use my mouse.

What's my best move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command, but isn't a keybinding by default, but you can bind one.

Go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Environment** > **Keyboard** and in "Show commands containing:" search for **Build.PublishSelection**, then you can bind whatever key combo you want to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at a file in the project you want to publish, hold down alt then type B, H, P.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + w + s

select the project in the solution explorer you want to publish

alt + b to access build menu

select publish your_project_name